# Which tool should we use to develop SSRS reports for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, bids

I have **Visual Studio 2012** installed on my development machine (DEV), and there is an **SQL Server 2008 R2 database** which is hosted on another server (DATASERVER). Now, I have installed SSRS on DATASERVER.

Now, I want to design SSRS reports from my DEV machine. Any idea of which tool I should install on my DEV machine for this? I know there was BIDS for Visual Studio 2008, not sure how can I do for Visual Studio 2012.

Any help on this much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2012 installed you can get Data Tools from this link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843

Then you can open "Data tools for Visual Studio 2012" and create your project from there.

Answer (score 0):

Business studio development studio was in sql server 2008 and also in sql server 2012 you can use `Data Tools`.
It is a part of visual studio that has reporting service,analysis service, and integration service parts.